# Flat array from an array of structs?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Hey guys. Thanks for clicking.

This is a problem that I'm encountering while coding OpenGL, but it's a pretty general problem overall - so nothing graphics specific.

I have a struct (not a class, just a simply struct), Particle.

```
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}float3;

typedef struct
{
   float3 position;
   float3 velocity;
   //...other stuff
}Particle;
```

And I am working with a bunch of particles (Particle* particles[]), but I have a function that requires a float* of positions packed in an x, y, z order.

Thus a summary of my problem:

My data:

```
//I have this in a bunch of encapsulated structs
[... {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f,} ... {4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f} ...]

//I want...
[1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f, 5.0f, 6.0f]
```

My problem is...I have all the data there already! I don't want to have to malloc/memcpy around again. Is there a way to use the data that is already there? Any C pointer acrobatics? I am also worrying about things like alignment/padding.

(float3 is a struct defined in CUDA, if anyone is curious).

Comment: It seems to depend a lot on what you want the single array for--if you just need to pick out an element using an index 0-5, you can write a simple method for that.

Comment: I assume you cannot change the function and have it accept a `Particle*` instead? The `position`s are not sequential (they have `velocity` and other stuff in their middle) so you have to copy data around. Sorry :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`glVertexAttribPointer` has a `stride` parameter that is designed for just this situation.

Typically you will load an array of `Particle` objects into a VBO, and then, with the VBO bound:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(shader_arg_position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof (Particle), offsetof(Particle, position));
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is more C oriented.

The thing with pointers,you can use them to walk freely from one memory address to another with the idea "don't care what data is there". Combine that with the fact that when you allocate structs they are aligned in the order they are declared and you have yourself an easy solution to access your data without too much hassle.

Just make a `float* index` to point at the beginning of your vector structure where you hold all the points. Using `index` now you can traverse it how you please, *however* be careful where you stop with the pointer movement.

---

To explain a bit:

```
struct {
  float3 position;
  float3 velocity;
  float3 more_data;
} Particle;
```

When you allocate this structure the memory will look like this:

`3 floats for position` || `3 floats for velocity` || `3 floats for whatever data`

Take a `float*` at the address `position.x` and increment it through you particles taking in consideration what data you want to process (position, velocity, etc).

Concerning alignment, it depends what alignment do you want your structure to have.

Comment: It won't work ... the original array has `pos, pos, pos, vel, vel, vel, other stuff, other stuff, pos, pos, pos, vel, ...` and TheChariot wants only the `pos`

Comment: He can jump with that index wherever he wants, if he can adapt his function to this type of movement. If not I don't see a workaround.

Comment: Your edit assumes the function can be changed. If it can be changed, the best thing to do is to have it accept a pointer to a Particle :)

Answer (score -1):

What about a reinterpret cast and a lot of care here?

```
Particle* pP[];
// Fill your array of particles
// And now at your own risk (memory accesses and so on... :)
float* pF = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&pP[0]);
float x = pF[0];
float y = pF[1];
float z = pF[2];
pF = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&pP[1]);
// ..
```

If you have your Particle* array, but you want to work with it as if it were an array of float positions, you could write something like this:

```
float getNthFloat(size_t n)
{
  size_t i = n / 3;
  size_t j = n % 3;
  float* pF = reinterpret_cast<float*>(&pP[i]);
  return pF[j];
}
// This would get 6th element in your virtual float array
// That is, second z position
size_t foo = 5;
float blah = getNthFloat(5);
```

And going one step further; you could probably rewrite this so it actually looks like accessing an array instead of calling a function.

Comment: If you want a `float[3]` out of a single `float3` this would do the trick. But if you want a `float[3N]` out of a `Particle[N]` you'll end up with the other `float3` objects getting in the way.

Answer (score -5):

The ideal solution is to fire whoever designed `float3` and replace this structure with simple arrays across the board.

If you can't do that, you can try simply casting the pointer, but you might find your compiler refuses to generate working code since this is a violation of the aliasing rules.

And one more solution:

```
typedef struct {
    float elem[3];
} float3;
#define x elem[0]
#define y elem[1]
#define z elem[2]
```

Unfortunately the names `x`, `y`, and `z` could be problematic to define as macros like this. That's one reason many classic C structures use prefixed names for struct elements, like `st_dev`, `tv_sec`, `si_uid`, etc...

Comment: This is probably not an option and not helping solve TheChariot's problem.

Comment: You've obviously never done anything with real-time graphics.

Comment: @Joce In fact casting is the first suggestion towards a solution that this thread has seen.  reinterpret_cast<float*> on the appropriate slice of Particle is maybe worth a try.

Comment: @OJL Actually I have, and I would never use a `struct` in a context where an array would sometimes be useful, precisely because you'll get into situations like this where you either have to fight with the compiler's aliasing rules or make your code slow due to needless copying.

Comment: So you fire somebody, and replace `float3` with an array. How does this remove the velocity information from the Particle structure?

Comment: OK, I think I missed the second half of what OP wants. I don't see any easy fix for that except possibly seriously changing the format of the data... :(

Comment: @Matt Phillips: The original answer was something like: "Fire the guy that created float3", hence my comment.